Unable to retrieve result for "kv/data/path" because it was not found: {"errors":["no handler for route 'kv/data/path'"]}
I have been trying to incorporate vault action in my github actions.
I see the error:
GetSecrets:
    name: Import Secrets
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - name: Import the secrets from Vault
      id: import-secrets
      uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v3
      with:
        url: VAULT_URL
        caCertificate: ${{ secrets.VAULT_CA_CERTIFICATE }}
        token: ${{ secrets.VAULT_TOKEN }}
        secrets: |
            kv/data/path username | USERNAME;

Unable to retrieve result for "kv/data/path" because it was not found: {"errors":["no handler for route 'kv/data/path'"]}
Although the same path works if I create a Jenkins pipeline, without kv/data.

What is the secrets engine?

engineVersion: 2
@MatthewSchuchard

Is "kv/data/path" correct? Have you used the correct "path", right?

Yes, I have used the correct path.
